$I_{\nu}/\nu^{3}$ which is Lorentz invariant is also invariant for cosmological redshift?
$I_{\nu}/\nu^{3}$ is Lorentz invariant, therefore an observed intensity is boosted by $\delta^{3}$, where $\delta$ is the Doppler factor. If the cosmological redshift is same physical process with Doppler shift, an observed intensity might be deboosted by $\frac{1}{(1+z)^3}$, where $z$ is a redshift. However, cosmological redshift is explained to be different from Doppler shift. When an observed intensity can be presented by $I_{\mathrm{obs}}=(1+z)^{n}I_{\mathrm{int}}$, is $n=-3$ like the case of Doppler shift? If not, what is the value of $n$?
